# display min and max value of user input and also find the average

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, iterator, average

Hi there I am a beginner, I have looked at similar query's but i was wondering if anyone could help me with my code. I am working on an assignment to receive numbers from user input and print out the maximum value and minimum value that the user has inserted. I was wondering how I would do this without using arrays. This is what I have so far:

```
  public void analyseLevels() {
    UI.clearText();
    UI.printf("Insert pollution levels followed%nby a space in between%nuse 
   'done' to insert:%n");
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int input = 0;
    double av = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        while(UI.hasNextInt()){
        int  amt = UI.nextInt();
    // Initialise variables
    // Prompt for input
    // Loop, reading numbers and updating variables
    // Compute and print out the analysis
        if( amt > 0){

        if(amt > max){
          max = amt;

        }

        if(amt < min){
          min = amt;

        }

        if(amt >= 120){
          UI.printf("Dangerous level: %dppb%n", amt);
        }

        sum += amt;
        count++;
      }

        av = ( sum ) / ( count );
        UI.println( "Average = " + av );
        UI.println( "Max = " + max );
        UI.println( "Minimum = " + min );

   }
    UI.nextLine(); // to clear out the input
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? You have a integer division issue here `av = ( sum ) / ( count );`, and should something more like `av = ( sum ) / ( (double)count );`

Comment: what's the issue now? Any error exception?

Comment: still you are not using array !!! so what is the issue??

Comment: when I insert: 10 20 30 40 121 123 145 done
the outcome is : Average = 10.0
Max = 10
Minimum = 10
Average = 15.0
Max = 20
Minimum = 10
Average = 20.0
Max = 30
Minimum = 10
Average = 25.0
Max = 40
Minimum = 10
Dangerous level: 121ppb
Average = 44.0
Max = 121
Minimum = 10
Dangerous level: 123ppb
Average = 57.0
Max = 123
Minimum = 10
Dangerous level: 145ppb
Average = 69.0
Max = 145
Minimum = 10

I want it to print just the max and just the min and the average of all the numbers that the user inputted. 

@MadProgrammer

Comment: I have stated the issue above thanks 
@SMA

Comment: I have stated the issue above thanks @Prashant

Comment: put your while loop end bracket before calculating average and check whether you are getting right answer or not??

Comment: Thank you so much! I put  av = ( sum ) / ( count );
        UI.println( "Average = " + av );
        UI.println( "Max = " + max );
        UI.println( "Minimum = " + min );
outside of while loop and it worked how i wanted it to :)
@Prashant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting while loop end bracket `}` wrongly.

**put your while loop end bracket before calculating average**

Answer (score 1):

Bring your println/avergae calculation statement out of loop like:

```
 }//while loop ends
 av = ( sum ) / ( (double)count);
 UI.println( "Average = " + av );
 UI.println( "Max = " + max );
 UI.println( "Minimum = " + min );
```